# MySQLi change database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am making a database connection this way:

`$mysqli = new mysqli('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'database_'.$_SESSION['db_selected']);`

I want the ability to change the database by changing a selectbox on top, this is working. Session gets rewritten to the right database, but it remains connected to the original selected database.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried overwriting the $mysqli variable, but no luck.

Comment: Close your database when clicking on an option in your select box could solve the problem I think

Comment: Do you update `$_SESSION['db_selected']` before or after connecting to the database?

Comment: MySQLi doesn't support multi databases

Comment: @turson Yes it does, [`mysqli::select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one while changing the database:

```
mysqli_close ( $mysqli )
```

Comment: +1 Also, as an extra tid-bit. If you have multiple databases within this one connection, you can simply call [`mysqli::select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) to change the database versus having the overhead of closing the connection and re-opening the connection.